# Printing dict Showing keyerror

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to PY.

I was reading a code and tried it locally.

```
ta = 'aa'print('{{"test":"{}"}}'.format(ta))
```

While if I remove one pair of curly braces it throws me key error.

```
ta = 'aa'print('{"test":"{}"}'.format(ta))
```

Resulting in

```
{"test":"aa"}
```

But when we see there were 2 curly bracket but it returned only one why is that?

thanks

Comment: Because that's how you escape literal braces in a format string.

Answer (score 0):

When you using .format method it looks for a curly braces, which it replace with any values. If you want to print braces, but not replace it with any value you need to write double-braces. You can read about Python3 format methods more detailed in [this article](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).